# Change soundName of already set UILocalNotification

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, alert, uilocalnotification

It is changed for notifications that are yet to be created (new notifications), but for those who are already created, the previous sound stays.

I have tried:

```
NSString *soundName = cell.titleLabel.text;

NSArray *notifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];

for (UILocalNotification *notif in notifications) {
    notif.soundName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3", soundName];
}
```

but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

You have to reschedule the notifications that you've scheduled. But make sure you remove the ones that you've scheduled previously.

```
NSArray *notifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

for (UILocalNotification *notif in notifications) {
    notif.soundName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3", soundName]; 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```